# how to view reports of jasperserver in php

Tags: php, report

I am a freshman and just starting Java. I created and published some reports to jasper server using iReport, now what I want to do is instead of logging into jasper server, I want to view my reports in my own site.

I tried it by using php/java bridge but not got the solution.

Can any body provide me the steps to be followed in clear manner?

Comment: Santhi,

Looks like it's been a while since you asked this question. Have you had any more luck with Jasper?

Answer (score 0):

Santhi,

You will probably want to stay away from bridging technologies if you're just starting out. It will probably be easiest to stick with just one technology, iReport, for this. Build and run your report in iReport, then export the compiled report to PDF. From there, you could host that PDF on your PHP site. No, it will not be dynamic, but you will have much less to chew in each step, and you can build on the solution as you have time and experience.

Yours,

David S